# CV2 OpenCL, cv2.UMat object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencl, opencv

I'm using pyzbar library to decode QRcodes. Now I'm trying to use uMat to make this process more quickly. The problem is that pyzbar decode cannot accept umat variable.

> File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\pyzbar.py", line 175, in decode
>       pixels, width, height = image
>   TypeError: 'cv2.UMat' object is not iterable

Here is my code sample

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(True)

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("Images"):
    for file in sorted(files):
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".JPG"):

            image = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            image = cv2.UMat(image)

            symbols = decode(image)

            if symbols:
                plt.title(symbols[0][0])
                plt.imshow(image)
                plt.show()
```

Comment: `UMat` is not just a numpy array, it's an OpenCV class. Why are you using it outside of OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IU guess the reason for that error can be found in the documentation of decode from pyzbar:

```
def decode(image, symbols=None, scan_locations=False):
"""Decodes datamatrix barcodes in `image`.
Args:
    image: `numpy.ndarray`, `PIL.Image` or tuple (pixels, width, height)
    symbols (ZBarSymbol): the symbol types to decode; if `None`, uses
        `zbar`'s default behaviour, which is to decode all symbol types.
    scan_locations (bool): If `True`, results will include scan
        locations.
```

Decode expects an image or a matrix containing the data in a specific order, which is fullfilled by a mat-instance supported by OpenCV. The UMat-format does not fullfil this requirement and so the error will be occur.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand my mistake. Is there a way to format UMat to numpy again?

Comment: @ADIN Just don't convert ndarray to UMat in the first place?

Comment: @Georgy I didnt show in this example rest of my code where I have cv2 operations which could be improved by Umat.

Comment: @JeruLuke I still want to know how to reverse this process. uMat > ndarray

Comment: @ADIN I don't know. But perhaps there is no need for that. You can display and write an image of the type `cv2.UMat` anyway. Why do you need to convert it anyway?

Comment: @ADIN  You can pass from UMat to numpy with the following instruction: yourmat = cv2.UMat.get(yourumat)